# MassAssignmentSecurity Error when using attr_encrypted (attr_encryptor) gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment, attr-encrypted

For my rails 3.2.3 app, I am using attr_encryptor, which is a fork by danpal of attr_encrypted. I have followed the instructions as given [here](https://github.com/danpal/attr_encryptor#readme), but I am getting the following error message when I try to create a new `Patient` record:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in PatientsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: mrn, last_name, first_name, date_of_birth(1i), date_of_birth(2i), date_of_birth(3i)
```

As the instructions say, I have added `encrypted_#{field}`, `encrypted_#{field}_salt`, and `encrypted_#{field}_iv` columns to my `Patients` table while dropping their non-encrypted counterparts.

The `Patient` model looks like:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :gender
  attr_encrypted :last_name, :key => 'key 1'
  attr_encrypted :first_name, :key => 'key 2'
  attr_encrypted :mrn, :key => 'key 3'
  attr_encrypted :date_of_birth, :key => 'key 4'
  # ...
end
```

My `create` method in my `Patient` controller looks like:

```
PatientsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def create
    @patient = Patient.new
    @patient.first_name = params[:patient][:first_name]
    @patient.last_name = params[:patient][:last_name]
    @patient.mrn = params[:patient][:mrn]
    @patient.date_of_birth = Date.new(params[:patient]['date_of_birth(1i)'],
                                      params[:patient]['date_of_birth(2i)'],
                                      params[:patient]['date_of_birth(3i)'])
    if @patient.save
      # do stuff
    else
      # do other stuff
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark these attributes with `attr_accessible` as well as `attr_encrypted` since the latter does not imply the former.

This might also be relevant for the date field: [Correct way to handle multiparameter attributes corresponding to virtual attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482507/correct-way-to-handle-multiparameter-attributes-corresponding-to-virtual-attribu)